# Banshee doesn't seem to play any song, but works in audacious?

Tags: 14.04, lubuntu, music, banshee

I've just downloaded Banshee to use as my main audio UI, and when I imported everything over onto the UI it won't seem to play any of my songs.  I'm using Lubuntu 14.04 LTS and have looked at the previous similar topics on this question and it doesn't seem to work.

I've tried this:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Just to see if the files weren't corrupted or anything, I burned an audio cd and the cd works perfectly fine.  Also I see the term "idle" displayed below where the track "ticker" (I guess) is; to the right of where the skip/play buttons are.

Any ideas of what I can do to get songs to play on here?  Just was concerned if Banshee is still all the way functional or not, or maybe I got the wrong version?

Comment: Did you rebooted the computer after install ubuntu-restricted-extras ? Maybe, some codecs are missing.

Comment: Yeah I did.  I'm not sure what would be missing, because my audacious player seems to be working perfectly fine. ... hmmm.

Comment: As VLC, some players have their own codecs alongside the app. So, these applications does not use the system wide codecs as Banshee does. Check your gstreamer installation: `gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly-multiverse`

Answer (score 0):

You need tell us how it fails.

Maybe it is playing but your output channel is silent/muted. I have seen that.  You can't tell in base gui sometimes, a button says volume is not muted. However, that may not track the method (channel)the player is wanting to use. Because there are many audio frameworks loaded at once, watch out!. New installs may have Pulseaudio, alsa or some other, who knows what else. Depends on your sound card too. Ubuntu recommends Rhythmbox, often it ok. Banshee not in base, possibly because of config problem.  Some players only work with one, alsa or oss. Jargon changes over time.

I had no sound from rhythmbox, because out channel was off. Pretty consistently, if I use Record My Desktop I cannot hear playback without hacking a while.

Here's how to tell.
Install pavucontrol to get control, see if output is muted. Pavucontrol is more modern gui, but if player is sending to wrong device, you see/fix that in alsamixer. Pavucontrol has meter on output to show if player is making noise. In alsa mixer, you can see if simpler old style programs are blocked.

Sad, but true. Multimedia has been a mess for a long time. I've been in Linux 20 years and is only thing that stays consistently difficult. 
There is a good reason Ubuntu does not ship a lot of those player programs anymore. And when you start installing others, there are likely sideeffects on base tools. It is only area in Ubuntu where I follow distro leaders' advice. It probable easier to change desktop evnironment than figure out sound.

Sorry I so gloomy. Long day at work.